# How to install Ubuntu Touch RTM 14.09 on Nexus 7 flo?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I have the Nexus 7 (flo) unlocked, rebooted and waiting:

```
magnus@Lubuntu:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
09e08081    device
magnus@Lubuntu:~$ adb reboot bootloader
magnus@Lubuntu:~$ fastboot devices
09e08081    fastboot
magnus@Lubuntu:~$ ubuntu-device-flash --list-channels
magnus@Lubuntu:~$ ubuntu-device-flash --channel=ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09 --bootstrap
2014/12/04 21:48:56 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2014/12/04 21:48:56 Device is |flo|
2014/12/04 21:48:56 Failed to locate latest image information
```

What am I doing wrong or is it not ready for idiots yet - should I wait a while longer?

Answer (score 0):

I used this command instead and it worked:

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel=ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09-proposed --bootstrap
```

In Ubuntu Touch now...